# How to say reference in Russian?

Tags: перевод

I would like to find a translation of the word "reference" into Russian in the following sentence:

"Please provide the names and contact information for three references"

Here reference is a person that can provide a reference letter.

I would like to give a context for this question. I am Russian living in UK for last 12 years working in academia. Clearly this phrase is more than familiar for me, since we are constantly asked to provide references in UK, US, etc. Nowadays there are certain institutions in Russia that are trying to copycat  western practices. In particular one needs to translate these type of phrases into Russian. I genuinely think that the meaning of the word "reference" as a human being is not yet worked out in Russian language, or maybe it is worked out but I am not aware of it. This was my reason to ask the question.

For example, been native Russian speaker, I never encountered the word "рекомендатель" and I am not sure if it usage is common in Russian academia.

Comment: it's indeed a not very common word but not unknown, examples from the corpora:[рекомендатель](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mode=main&env=&text=lexform&req=рекомендатель&mycorp=created:1988*&sort=gr_tagging) [рекомендателя](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mode=main&env=&text=lexform&req=рекомендателя&sort=gr_tagging), [рекомендателем](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mode=main&env=&text=lexform&req=рекомендателем&sort=gr_tagging), [рекомендателю](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mode=main&env=&text=lexform&req=рекомендателю&sort=gr_tagging)

Comment: even if ***рекомендатель*** isn't very common it's absolutely understandable and not least because of being built according to the morphological rules of Russian and sounding natural, in my opinion

Comment: if Russian institutions demand such documents there's a chance they have laid out rules of their provision and their templates, this is where the exact word they use can be looked up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More context would help.

Let's say **рекомендатель**

In [Multitran](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=reference) we have

> лицо, дающее рекомендацию
>   лицо, способное дать рекомендацию

which are too unwieldy

So here.

UPD: [here's an example](http://www.hr-portal.ru/doki/blank-proverki-rekomendaciy-na-soiskatelya) of a references form found online which uses the term **рекомендатель**

[image: 1]

Answer (score 6):

I would translate as:

> Пожалуйста предоставьте три рекомендации(положительных отзыва) с именами и контактной информацией(контактными данными).